# Typescript Type - append string for each key in object

Tags: typescript

Given the following object:

```js
const testFunctions = {
   test: () => 'test',
   test2: ( yo: string ) => console.log('test2')
}
```

and this `addCommands` function that maps the same functions but appends the component name.

```js
const addCommands = <N extends string, T extends Record<string, any>>(name: N, myFunctions: Readonly<T>) => {
   const commands = {};
   
   Object.keys(myFunctions).forEach((key) => {
      const name = `${name}_${key}`;
      commands[name] = myFunctions[key];
   }

   // Cypress.Commands.addAll(commands); // ignore this
   return commands
}
```

when I call the `addCommands` function:

```js
const mappedCommands = addCommands('testing', testFunctions );
```

the returned type should be of type:

```js
/*
{
   testing_test: () => string;
   testing_test2: (yo: string) => void
}
*/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOAjRm) meet your needs?  Note I had to fix some errors in your implementation to get it to work, and I didn't bother trying to get type safety in the function implementation (I just use `any` inside the function so there are no compiler errors)... but the return value and type are what you want.  If that fully addresses the question I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: Hi, yes this works. I had been close but I didn't know about the `in string` I had errors to do with key not being a string. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In what follows I'm only concerned with the *call signature* of `addCommands()`, not its *implementation*.  That call signature should look like:

```
declare const addCommands: <N extends string, T extends Record<string, any>>(
  name: N, myFunctions: T
) => { [K in (string & keyof T) as `${N}_${K}`]: T[K]; }
```

This is using [key remapping in mapped types via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to convert each string-valued key `K` in the keys of `T` to a version prepended with the type of `name` and an underscore.  Since `name` is of type `N`, the new key type is the [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) `` `${N}_${K}` ``.

Note that if you just write `` {[K in keyof T as `${N}_${K}`]: T[K]} `` you get an error that `K` can't appear in a template literal type.  That's because, in general, the keys you get from [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) are some subtype of `PropertyKey`, and these include [`symbol`-valued keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html), which TypeScript doesn't want to let you serialize (after all, an actual [template literal value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would produce a runtime error if you tried to do that).

To prevent that error we can restrict the keys over which `K` ranges.  One way is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `keyof T` with `string`, like `(string & keyof T)`, to get just the string-valued keys.  You could write `((string | number) & keyof T)` if you want to support `number` keys (so that `{0: ""}` gets mapped to `{test_0}` instead of `{}`).  Or `Exclude<keyof T, symbol>` using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion), et cetera. The point is to convince the compiler that you're not going to try to serialize any `symbol`s.

---

Let's test it:

```
const testFunctions = {
  test: () => 'test',
  test2: (yo: string) => console.log('test2')
}

const mappedCommands = addCommands('testing', testFunctions);
/* const mappedCommands: {
    testing_test: () => string;
    testing_test2: (yo: string) => void;
} */
```

Looks good, that's the type you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=6&ssc=9&pln=5&pc=49#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-ClzWF0A)